# DataGrid2D - 'Attachable Property' warning in VS 2019

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I'm using the DataGrid2D component (installed via NuGet) to allow me to bind a 2D array to a datagrid in a .Net Core 3.1 WPF project using Prism.
https://github.com/GuOrg/Gu.Wpf.DataGrid2D/blob/master/README.md

Everything works it's just that the designer breaks and VS gives me the following warning for the code snippet shown below:
*The Attachable Property 'Array2D' was not found in type 'ItemSource'*

[image: warning]

Here's the alias I included in the top of the xaml page:
[image: alias]

Any ideas how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly I think this may be just one of countless bugs in the WPF designer.
Does it work when you run it?

You can try a sad loop of closing vs, git clean, rebuild etc. and maybe it goes away.

Comment: Yes - it works great when I run the application!  I think I might try setting the attached properties from the code behind (if I can figure out the syntax).  This might keep the designer happy.